# Create a real time graph (with nodejs)

Tags: python, node.js, real-time, plotly

I wrote a program in raspberry (with python) which use a movement sensor to say if a room is empty (when there is no movement for example) or not. If the room is empty, the raspberry send "0" to my server (and it send "1" in the other case). (I know that's a simple use case and that's not perfect but I just want to switch to visualization). So what I want to do is to create a real time graph to visualize the data send by my raspberry. It's really a simple use case.

Since I have already used nodejs, I want to create that graph with the same language. I don't know if there are more simple and more powerful API or libraries for that. But now, I tried to use plotly : https://plot.ly/streaming/

There is my code :

```
    var data = {
        'x':x0,'y':y0, 
        'type':'scatter', 
        'mode':'lines+markers', 
         marker: {
            color: "rgba(31, 119, 180, 0.96)"
        }, 
        line: {
            color:"rgba(31, 119, 180, 0.31)"
        }, 
        stream: {
            "token": "ikx23jsxtj", //token that I generate
            "maxpoints": 1000
        }
    }

    var graphOptions = {
        "filename": "Room State", 
        "fileopt": "overwrite",
        "layout": {
            "title": "Raspberry"
        },
        "world_readable": true
    }

    plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) return console.log("ERROR", err)

        console.log(resp)

        var plotlystream = plotly.stream("ikx23jsxtj", function () {})
        var signalstream = ..... //the problem is that I have NO idea what I should write here


        plotlystream.on("error", function (err) {
            signalstream.destroy()
        })

        data.pipe(plotlystream)
    })
```

Comment: What precisely is your question: Is something not working with your code? Are you looking for better alternatives?

Comment: The code is not working because I have no graph... In fact, I don't know what I should put in the "signalstream" variable